# Why is KerasCV augmentation layer destructively editing image labels?

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision, tensorflow-datasets, yolov8, keras-cv

I'm currently approximately following Gitesh Chawda's guide for YOLOV8 from [here](https://keras.io/examples/vision/yolov8/)

Everything is going as expected until the image augmentation stage, at which point the images are correctly augmented, but the corresponding labels are effectively destroyed (but the shape of the structure remains)

Edit: I've added a minimal reproducible example here
https://github.com/jacky-ct/SampleData

```
def to_tf_format(img_path, img_class, img_box):
    image = tf.io.read_file(img_path)
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image, channels=3)

    print(f"img = {image}, cls = {img_class}, box = {img_box}")

    classes = tf.cast(img_class, dtype = tf.float32)
    boxes = tf.cast(img_box, dtype = tf.float32)

    bounding_boxes = {
        "classes": classes,
        "boxes": boxes,
    }

    return {"images": tf.cast(image, tf.float32), "bounding_boxes": bounding_boxes}

augmentor = keras.Sequential(
    layers=[
        keras_cv.layers.RandomFlip(mode="horizontal", bounding_box_format="rel_xyxy"),
        keras_cv.layers.RandomShear(
            x_factor=0.2, y_factor=0.2, bounding_box_format="rel_xyxy"
        ),
        keras_cv.layers.JitteredResize(
            (640, 640), scale_factor = (0.7, 1.3), bounding_box_format="rel_xyxy"
        ),
    ]
)

def dict_to_tuple(inputs):
    return inputs["images"], inputs["bounding_boxes"]

train_ds = train_data.map(to_tf_format, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
train_ds = train_ds.shuffle(BATCH_SIZE * 4)
train_ds = train_ds.ragged_batch(BATCH_SIZE, drop_remainder=True)
train_ds = train_ds.map(augmentor, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

train_ds = train_ds.map(dict_to_tuple, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
train_ds = train_ds.prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
```

With the output of the print statement in `to_tf_format` being:

```
img = Tensor("DecodeJpeg:0", shape=(None, None, 3), dtype=uint8), cls = Tensor("RaggedFromVariant/RaggedTensorFromVariant:0", shape=(None,), dtype=int32), box = Tensor("RaggedFromVariant_1/RaggedTensorFromVariant:0", shape=(None, 4), dtype=float64)
```

to give an idea of the structure of the data. Checking the form of the data after this transformation gives an expected output if I don't apply any preprocessing -`next(iter(train_ds.take(1)))[0]` gives:

```
<tf.RaggedTensor [[[[74.0, 79.0, 83.0],
   [76.0, 81.0, 85.0],
   [79.0, 84.0, 88.0],
   ...,
   [59.0, 87.0, 126.0],
   [57.0, 85.0, 124.0],
   [56.0, 84.0, 123.0]],

  [[71.0, 76.0, 80.0],
   [73.0, 78.0, 82.0],
   [75.0, 80.0, 84.0],
   ...,
   [61.0, 89.0, 126.0],
   [60.0, 88.0, 125.0],
   [58.0, 86.0, 123.0]],

  [[67.0, 75.0, 77.0],
   [68.0, 76.0, 78.0],
   [69.0, 77.0, 79.0],
   ...,
   [67.0, 96.0, 130.0],
   [67.0, 96.0, 130.0],
   [65.0, 94.0, 128.0]],

  ...,
...
   [58.0, 55.0, 38.0],
   ...,
   [67.0, 62.0, 43.0],
   [71.0, 66.0, 47.0],
   [74.0, 69.0, 50.0]]]]>
```

and `next(iter(train_ds(1)))[1]` gives:

```
{'classes': <tf.RaggedTensor [[7.0], [7.0, 7.0], [7.0], [7.0]]>,
 'boxes': <tf.RaggedTensor [[[0.4369476, 0.92896473, 0.43951866, 0.9240088]],
  [[0.6037169, 0.8419604, 0.6054107, 0.8397577],
   [0.60536873, 0.89794916, 0.60703814, 0.8959251]],
  [[0.42042324, 0.50033903, 0.43218476, 0.4572454]],
  [[0.6108871, 0.14179516, 0.61400294, 0.13711454]]]>}
```

When I perform ANY kind of preprocessing (i.e. each layer individually has this effect, leading me to believe I'm packing my data wrong), the output of `next(iter(train_ds.take(1)))[0]` is of the same form, but the output of `next(iter(train_ds.take(1)))[1]` is 4 empty objects, one for each item in my batch size:

```
{'classes': <tf.RaggedTensor [[], [], [], []]>,
 'boxes': <tf.RaggedTensor [[], [], [], []]>}
```

Obviously the expected behaviour would be that the tensors are populated with the augmented bounding box values.

Any help is greatly appreciated - I've done a lot of research and can't figurte out where I'm going wrong.

Comment: I did not manage to reproduce your issue. Did you use the same dataset as in the tutorial? It appears that you are using relative XYXY coordinate format for bounding boxes whereas the tutorial uses XYXY format. If you give XYXY format as input to your `augmentor` requiring rel_XYXY format, this could result in empty transformed data.

Comment: @JackPote I'm using my own dataset which uses rel_xyxy bounding boxes - if I try to visualise the data without augmenting it, the bounding boxes work as expected so I know that they're correctly formatted.